# How to zero/sign extend bitvectors in Z3?

Tags: z3, smt

I was unable to perform zero extension on a bitvector using Z3 SMT interface. From what I've learned by reading sources, there are functions for this, and they are available for various bindings (C, C++, Python, etc.), but the tutorial for SMT interface gives no clue how to call them.

Using `zero_extend` from the SMT QF_BV logic standard doesn't help too - Z3 says `unsupported`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that `zero_extend` and some other functions are **parametric** ones, probably something like `foo<T>` in C++. To call such functions one need to use special syntax:

```
(declare-const a (_ BitVec 1))
(declare-const b (_ BitVec 2))
(assert (= b ((_ zero_extend 1) a)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Using `((_ zero_extend i) x)` instead of `(zero_extend i x)` gives correct result:

```
sat
(model
  (define-fun a () (_ BitVec 1) #b0)
  (define-fun b () (_ BitVec 2) #b00)
)
```

Comment: That's absolutely correct, zero_extend is parametric (among others). I think of it as $f_i$ in Latex syntax.